# Customizing the paginator view in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I've been reading the docs and set up a basic app.
Every issue I've had before I've been able to solve by looking in the docs and occasionally using Google, however I can't figure this one out.

I'm using Laravel version 5.2.43 and the Paginator works fine.
I use it in my view like this,

```
$data->links()
```

But now I would like to customize the look of the paginator.
So I tried running this command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

In the hopes of simply being able to customize that view instead of creating a new one all over but that command didn't work, it just said

```
Nothing to publish for tag [laravel-pagination]
```

So, instead I did this.

```
{{ $data->links('folder.viewName') }}
```

But this command gives me this error,

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::links() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Presenter, string given
```

So I'm not sure what's going on. The pagination works but I can't set the view myself.
Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can't do this in Laravel 5.2 without "hacking" the framework. Fortunately, Laravel 5.3 is released this week and it features custom pagination views

[Custom pagination in Laravel 5.3](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/customizing-pagination-templates-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: At first I thought you were wrong because I've seen the function in the docs. Then I looked at my URL "/docs/5.3"... I've been reading the 5.3 documentation this entire time...

Comment: I've had that some many times when Google still thought the 4.2 release was newer than the 5.2 haha. Glad I could help! Maybe tick as an answer too..? ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I've been reading the 5.3 documentation for Laravel all this time. Which explains a lot of things...

So when 5.3 comes out we can do

```
$paginator->links("myOwnView")
```

Until then, I've done it the manual way of using the instances inside the paginator object.